# python can declare global variable in local scope?

Tags: python, scope

python can declare global variable in local scope?

It works:

```
def main():
    # do some... for files varible
    for file in files:
       result = func(file)
    print result
```

I can't understand.
Somebody tell me why `result` can be seen outside the `for` loop.

Thanks you.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking since it's not clear from what you've got so far.

Comment: i've added some modification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for` statements do not start a new scope. Only modules, class declarations, and function definitions start a new scope.

Comment: Unless they are inside list comprehensions (Py3k) or generator expressions (which are functions BTW)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't see a global variable declaration. `result` is a local variable, as is `file`. Are you talking about `files`? That looks like a global variable, but I don't see it declared locally.</strike>

*Update based on @DSM's helpful comment:*

If you are talking about `result` as being declared locally inside the `for`-loop, it doesn't work that way in Python, the `for`-loop doesn't create a local scope.

Comment: My wild guess is that the OP is surprised that `result` escapes the `for` loop.

Comment: @DSM Maybe .. hard to say .. still, I updated my answer with that in mind - thanks.

Comment: Looks like both me and IVA may have guessed wrong: now it seems like the OP is more surprised that `files` exists in scope, and by "declare" something like "refers to" is meant.. who can say? :)

Comment: @JamesDev Happy if I was able to help. I am not sure I'd call your questions "silly", but perhaps a bit unclear. Your most recent update to your post did clarify it though. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you a function uses assignment `=` or augemnted assignemnt (i.e. `+=`) then the variable is considered `local` by default. However, if you want to make the assignments `global` use the `global` keyword.

```
foo = 2
def bar():
    foo = 3 # foo is locally defined here

def car():
    global foo
    foo = 4 # foo is globally reassigned here

bar() # foo is still 2
car() # foo is now 4
```